# Rewrite the select statement without using dynamic sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a procedure with the following statements:

```
Create procedure usp_personCountry
@inPersonId Int,
@inType varchar(100)
As
Begin

If @inType = 'Admin'
Begin
  Select Distinct p.personid, p.name, p.email, pc.country, pa.attributeId
  From dbo.person p
  Inner Join dbo.personCountry pc
    on p.personId = pc.personId
  Inner Join dbo.personAttribute pa
    on p.personId = pa.personId
 Where p.personId = @inPersonId
  and pa.type     = 'Primary'
End
Else If @inType = 'Manager'
Begin 
 Select Distinct p.personid, p.name, p.email, pc.country, pa.attributeId
  From dbo.person p
  Inner Join dbo.personCountry pc
    on p.personId = pc.personId
  Inner Join dbo.personAttribute pa
    on p.personId = pa.personId
  Inner Join dbo.personCountryManager pcm
    on pa.personId = pcm.personId
 Where p.personId = @inPersonId
  and pa.type     = 'Manager'
End
Else If @inType = 'User'
Begin 
 Select Distinct p.personid, p.name, p.email, pc.country, pa.attributeId
  From dbo.person p
  Inner Join dbo.personCountry pc
    on p.personId = pc.personId
  Inner Join dbo.personAttribute pa
    on p.personId = pa.personId
  Inner Join dbo.personCountryUser pcm
    on pa.personId = pcm.personId
 Where p.personId = @inPersonId
  and pa.type     = 'User'
End
Else
Begin 
 Select Distinct p.personid, p.name, p.email, pc.country, pa.attributeId
  From dbo.person p
  Inner Join dbo.personCountry pc
    on p.personId = pc.personId
  Inner Join dbo.personAttribute pa
    on p.personId = pa.personId
  Inner Join dbo.personCountryTeam pcm
    on pa.personId = pcm.personId
 Where p.personId = @inPersonId
  and pa.type     = 'Team'
End

End /* End of procedure */
```

In the procedure above, the select statement is identical for all conditions. Every time I have to add a new column, I have to add it all the 4 statements and there is a high possibility that I might end up missing adding a column to one of the statements at some point. Is there a way to rewrite this sql query so that the select statement is used only once and based on the type passed in we can construct the query? I want to accomplish this without using dynamic sql. I was wondering if there is any way of doing it. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put if conditionals inline, for example using a [`CASE` expression](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/t-sql-queries/dirty-secrets-of-the-case-expression). However I do question the point of the `distinct`. Anyway you can do this with a little less repetition like this, but it can be quite wasteful:

```
  Select /* Distinct -- why? */ p.personid, 
    p.name, p.email, pc.country, pa.attributeId
  INTO #blat From dbo.person p
  Inner Join dbo.personCountry pc
    on p.personId = pc.personId
  Inner Join dbo.personAttribute pa
    on p.personId = pa.personId
 Where p.personId = @inPersonId
  and pa.type     = CASE @inType
                    WHEN 'Admin'   THEN 'Primary'
                    WHEN 'Manager' THEN 'Manager'
                    WHEN 'User'    THEN 'User'
                    ELSE                'Team' END;

IF @inType = 'Admin'
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM #blat;
END

IF @inType = 'Manager' 
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM #blat AS b WHERE EXISTS 
  (
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.personCountryManager WHERE personId = b.personId
  );
END 

IF @inType = 'User' 
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM #blat AS b WHERE EXISTS 
  (
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.personCountryUser WHERE personId = b.personId
  );
END 

IF @inType = 'Team' 
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM #blat AS b WHERE EXISTS 
  (
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.personCountryTeam WHERE personId = b.personId 
  );
END
```

Also I suspect it may be the case that as these tables get bigger and if there is any data skew at all, [dynamic SQL is actually a better option](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example).

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT 
    p.personid, p.name, p.email, pc.country, pa.attributeId
  From dbo.person p
  Inner Join dbo.personCountry pc
    on p.personId = pc.personId
  Inner Join dbo.personAttribute pa
    on p.personId = pa.personId';

SET @inType = CASE @inType WHEN 'Admin' THEN 'Primary' ELSE @inType END;

IF @inType <> 'Primary'
BEGIN
  SET @sql += N'
    Inner Join dbo.' + QUOTENAME(N'personCountry' + @inType) + ' pcm
      on pa.personId = pcm.personId';
END

SET @sql += N'
  Where p.personId = @inPersonId
  and pa.type     = @inType';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql, 
  N'@inPersonId int, @inType varchar(100)',
    @inPersonId,
    @inType;
```

Comment: Thank you, Aaron! The types - Manager, User, and Team have additional tables that I need to join to if you look at my stored procedure. Those are missing from your query.

Comment: @RobMartin got it, I missed that because you used the same alias `pcm` every time. You could left outer join to all of them, but again, I feel like dynamic SQL is the right answer. Can you explain why you don't want to use dynamic SQL? Fear? Your only other option is to repeat the query (you could eliminate _some_ repetition by creating a view or dumping intermediate results into a #temp table, but those are bad options too). Why don't you just have a PersonCountry table with a type column?

Comment: Thank you for the reply! My mentor doesn't like dynamic sql. He asked me to find other ways to accomplish this.

Comment: lol. ok. well... I don't think you're going to come to a solution that is much better than the one you already have. If your mentor doesn't like dynamic SQL, I hope he likes repetition.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will try to convince my mentor to use dynamic sql.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done, but the result would be a very, very convoluted query that would perform poorly. If (when) the tables get big, it could be a significant drain on server resources.

Dynamic SQL is an option, but here I think it's use would be clever, not smart (for "clever" is quite often the enemy of "smart"). The queries are sufficiently distinct that I'd suggest making a separate stored procedure for each situation (@inType value), and either call them directly from the application or use this procedure as a wrapper to call the appropriate stored procedure.

There might be an improvement made to the underlying table design? Can't tell with the information we have.

---

Below is the code I came up with--it is **NOT** a complete solution. I got up to the part that addresses the extra joins, and that logic is where it gets too confusticated to be a reasonable query.

```
--  Reset, to simplify logic
If @inType = 'Admin'
    SET @inType = 'Primary'


  Select Distinct p.personid, p.name, p.email, pc.country, pa.attributeId
  From dbo.person p
  Inner Join dbo.personCountry pc
    on p.personId = pc.personId
  Inner Join dbo.personAttribute pa
    on p.personId = pa.personId
  --  from 0 or 1 INNER JOIN to 3 left outer joins (and change alias)
  Left Outer Join dbo.personCountryManager pcm
    on pa.personId = pcm.personId
  Left Outer Join dbo.personCountryUser pcu
    on pa.personId = pcu.personId
  Left Outer Join dbo.personCountryTeam pct
    on pa.personId = pct.personId
 Where p.personId = @inPersonId
  --  Now, presumes parameter matches pa-type
  --  This is a problem if that final "else" is not always "Team"
  and pa.type = @inType
```

The above makes some assumptions regarding parameter @inType, and still has to factor in a check for "if @inType is X and the one relevant left outer joined table found an entry", and that's when it gets seriously ugly.

Comment: Thank you, Philip! Could you please elaborate on why using dynamic sql is not smart in this case?

Comment: I would also love to know why _carefully constructed_ dynamic SQL is "not smart."

Comment: "Carefully constructed" is the key phrase there. It is relatively easy to write dynamic SQL, and I have seen many cases where developers use it when it is not necessary, or the results are not at all efficient (which is why I am always leery of it--even when I use it myself). Here, a "carefully constructed" query might well run efficiently, but I believe the end result would be much the same as having four procedures that do not rely on dynamic code--and the code base would be that much more complex to support. (If columns are added frequently, the dynamic approach would simplify support.)

Comment: But by that argument then a car and a fork and a fridge and a razor blade are "not smart" - just because people _can_ do stupid things with them doesn't make them stupid.